# How to add binary diff viewer to tortise SVN & recommendations

Tags: tortoisesvn

I use tortiseSVN and frequently check in changes to binary files, does anyone know of a good diff visualizer and how to add it.

Comment: Your title and content are two different questions, but for the latter see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688504/binary-diff-tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in your title, there's information on such settings [over at the TortoiseSVN site](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-progs).

Basically:

- Open settings
- Expand 'External Programs'
- Select 'Diff Viewer'
- Configure in the right-hand pane.

As I commented, you have two different questions here, and the one asking for suggestions for binary diff tools has [already been covered here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688504/binary-diff-tool). I'd suggest you reference the the answers to that question to see if they are useful and target this question in one direction only.